# Ubuntu Firewall: Apache only visible on lan

Tags: apache2, firewall

How can I add a rule to the Ubuntu firewall that makes Apache server only accessible from the internal LAN?

**ufw status**

```
ng@ng-laptop-kv:~$ sudo ufw status
Estado: activo

Hasta                      Acción      Desde
-----                      ------      -----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: I would like to implement it using ufw, do think is possible?

Comment: If you are using `ufw` please include `sudo ufw status`

Comment: Right now it is accessible from Anywhere, just want to change it to someway it is only accesible from 192.168.0.*

Comment: :D i was giving you a full answer like @steeldriver did

Comment: hah np! @Achu do you know how to add the ipv6 rule to steeldriver's answer?

Comment: You can do like this: `sudo ufw allow proto ipv6 from x.x.x.x port 80`

Comment: mm it says incorrect port ipv6 ¿?

Comment: mm it was already in 'yes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an IP range using the `from` parameter, e.g. if your LAN IP range is 192.168.1.xxx

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
```

You will then need to delete the pre-exisiting less restrictive rule - I find it easiest to do that by rule number i.e. first use

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

and then (if the 'old' port 80 rule is #8 for example)

```
sudo ufw delete 8
```

and confirm (y|n). If you have/need IPv6 rules as well you will need to do the same for those.

Comment: and how to add ipv6 rule?

Comment: I do that but if I delete my old rules it doesnt work anymore

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct LAN IP range? BTW, if your LAN is behind a router (with NAT) and you didn't forward any ports to the Apache server host, then AFAIK it is not going to be accessible from outside the LAN anyway.

Comment: thanks you soo much @steeldriver, the range was wrong :)